# create a new nested JSON column in Snowflake

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert a few columns in Snowflake table into a nested JSON and have tried `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` & `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT` - but, unable to create a nested JSON

**Input:**

| id | product_1 | product_1_purchase_date | product_2 | product_2_purchase_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | XCTMR | 01/02/2003 | IOPWER | 01/02/2005 |
| 200 | AQWYU | 11/20/2016 | XCTMR | 09/09/2021 |

**Output:**

| id | json_combined |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | [ { "product_1": { "name": "XCTMR", "product_1_purchase_date": "01/02/2003" } }, { "product_2": { "name": "IOPWER", "product_2_purchase_date": "01/02/2005" } } ] |
| 200 | [ { "product_1": { "name": "AQWYU", "product_1_purchase_date": "11/20/2016" } }, { "product_2": { "name": "XCTMR", "product_2_purchase_date": "09/09/2021" } } ] |
|  |  |

Comment: Are you okay with hard-coding key values inside ```OBJECT_CONSTRUCT``` ?

Comment: Posted with hard-coding field names. Will try for something more dynamic later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, with hard-coding field-names only, just need to put functions `ARRAY_CONSTRUCT` and `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` in proper order.

```
with cte(id,product_1,product_1_purchase_date,product_2,product_2_purchase_date) as
(select * from values
(100,'XCTMR','01/02/2003','IOPWER','01/02/2005'),
(200,'AQWYU','11/20/2016','XCTMR','09/09/2021')
)select
  id,
  array_construct(object_construct('product_1',
  object_construct('name',product_1,'product_1_purchase_date',
  product_1_purchase_date)),
  object_construct('product_2',
  object_construct('name',product_2,'product_2_purchase_date',
  product_2_purchase_date)) ) as JSON_COMBINED
from cte;
+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
|  ID | JSON_COMBINED                                 |
|-----+-----------------------------------------------|
| 100 | [                                             |
|     |   {                                           |
|     |     "product_1": {                            |
|     |       "name": "XCTMR",                        |
|     |       "product_1_purchase_date": "01/02/2003" |
|     |     }                                         |
|     |   },                                          |
|     |   {                                           |
|     |     "product_2": {                            |
|     |       "name": "IOPWER",                       |
|     |       "product_2_purchase_date": "01/02/2005" |
|     |     }                                         |
|     |   }                                           |
|     | ]                                             |
| 200 | [                                             |
|     |   {                                           |
|     |     "product_1": {                            |
|     |       "name": "AQWYU",                        |
|     |       "product_1_purchase_date": "11/20/2016" |
|     |     }                                         |
|     |   },                                          |
|     |   {                                           |
|     |     "product_2": {                            |
|     |       "name": "XCTMR",                        |
|     |       "product_2_purchase_date": "09/09/2021" |
|     |     }                                         |
|     |   }                                           |
|     | ]                                             |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Below is with more dynamism -

- CTE is pure data.
- CTE_1 is creating two pseudo-columns, one for field name product_x and
  another to be used as grouping criteria later in `OBJECT_AGG` We
  cannot use aggregate function inside another aggregate function, so
  we need to do aggregation multiple times (twice here). Change divide by 2 in this CTE to the number of product_x columns. We can also add a sub-query here to do this calculation, but for the purpose of this solution I've left it as hard-coded.
  CTE_1 is also doing the main job of `UNPIVOT` product related column into rows for dynamic grouping.
- CTE_2 is aggregation number - 1, with output like below (showing truncated output). Final query does the main `ARRAY_AGG`.

```
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  ID | RN        | JSON_COMBINED_1                              |
|-----+-----------+----------------------------------------------|
| 100 | product_1 | {                                            |
|     |           |   "product_1": {                             |
|     |           |     "PRODUCT_1_PURCHASE_DATE": "01/02/2003", |
|     |           |     "name": "XCTMR"                          |
|     |           |   }                                          |
|     |           | }                                            |
| 200 | product_2 | {                                            |
|     |           |   "product_2": {                             |
|     |           |     "PRODUCT_2_PURCHASE_DATE": "09/09/2021", |
|     |           |     "name": "XCTMR"                          |
|     |           |   }                                          |
|     |           | }                                            |
+-----+-----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Main query -

```
with cte(id,product_1,product_1_purchase_date,product_2,product_2_purchase_date) as
 (select * from values
 (100,'XCTMR','01/02/2003','IOPWER','01/02/2005'),
 (200,'AQWYU','11/20/2016','XCTMR','09/09/2021')
),cte_1 as (
 select id,
 case when regexp_like(product_field,'product_[[:digit:]]+','i') 
 then 'name' else product_field end p_field,
 product_val,
 concat('product_',
 to_char(ceil(row_number() over (partition by id order by null)/2)))   rn
from cte
unpivot (product_val for product_field in  (product_1,product_1_purchase_date,
 product_2,product_2_purchase_date))
), cte_2 as (
 select id,rn,
 object_construct(rn,object_agg(p_field,to_variant(product_val)))  JSON_COMBINED_1
 from cte_1
 group by id,rn
) select id, array_agg(JSON_COMBINED_1) JSON_COMBINED
 from cte_2
 group by id
 order by id;
```

Final output from above query (with dynamism) -

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------+
|  ID | JSON_COMBINED                                  |
|-----+------------------------------------------------|
| 100 | [                                              |
|     |   {                                            |
|     |     "product_1": {                             |
|     |       "PRODUCT_1_PURCHASE_DATE": "01/02/2003", |
|     |       "name": "XCTMR"                          |
|     |     }                                          |
|     |   },                                           |
|     |   {                                            |
|     |     "product_2": {                             |
|     |       "PRODUCT_2_PURCHASE_DATE": "01/02/2005", |
|     |       "name": "IOPWER"                         |
|     |     }                                          |
|     |   }                                            |
|     | ]                                              |
| 200 | [                                              |
|     |   {                                            |
|     |     "product_2": {                             |
|     |       "PRODUCT_2_PURCHASE_DATE": "09/09/2021", |
|     |       "name": "XCTMR"                          |
|     |     }                                          |
|     |   },                                           |
|     |   {                                            |
|     |     "product_1": {                             |
|     |       "PRODUCT_1_PURCHASE_DATE": "11/20/2016", |
|     |       "name": "AQWYU"                          |
|     |     }                                          |
|     |   }                                            |
|     | ]                                              |
+-----+------------------------------------------------+
2 Row(s) produced.
```